# How to represent a tree of models with Ember Data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am looking  for a way to generate a D3.js data structure from an Ember model, to convert my existing app to Ember. The goal is to display a tree of tasks, each task having 0 or more subtasks.

Here is the result I want to feed to D3.js :

```
[
  {
    "parent": 429,
    "name": "Parent task 1",
    "id": 428
    "children": [
      {
        "parent": 428,
        "name": "Sub task 1",
        "id": 425
      },
      {
        "parent": 428,
        "name": "Sub task 2",
        "id": 426
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I tried to define my model like this :

```
Minp.Task = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),
  subtasks: DS.hasMany('task'),
  data: Ember.computed(function () {
    return {
      id: this.get('id'),
      name: this.get('name'),
      type: 'task',
      children: this.get('subtasks').map(function (task) {
        return task.get('data');
      })
    };
  }).property()
});
```

But I am getting a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. It seems that calling `this` from the `data` attributes causes it to be called again, in an infinite loop.

If i return an empty array for children, all works fine.

Do you have any idea why I am getting this ? Is it another way to do it ?

Comment: there is typo 'thisi' in your example. See model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is already a property on a DS.Model, and presumably it's getting invoked via the `get`s... which are now going into your redefinition of `data`, and causing your loop.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this ! I renamed the property to d3data and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off using associations, aren't you? Try using a self-referring data structure.

```
Minp.Task = DS.Model.extend({
  parent: DS.belongsTo('task', inverse: 'children');
  children: DS.hasMany('task', async: true, inverse: 'parent');
});
```

Hopefully that helps. Kind of depends what you want to do with these things, but that's what I generally use when I'm building tree-based data structures.